# Ensure an a timestamp column (event) is happening X times during Y period

Tags: postgresql

Fiddle in this [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8STbBxhQi72W65g59L1ccn/0).

I have a table with user_id and action_time:
**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE actions(
  action_time timestamp,
  user_id int
  );
  
insert into actions values ('2015-01-20 01:00',1);
insert into actions values ('2015-01-01 01:00',1);
insert into actions values ('2015-01-10 01:00',1);
insert into actions values ('2015-01-12 01:00',1);
insert into actions values ('2015-01-16 01:00',1);
insert into actions values ('2015-01-23 01:00',1);
insert into actions values ('2015-02-20 01:00',1);
insert into actions values ('2015-03-20 01:00',1);
insert into actions values ('2015-05-20 01:00',1);
insert into actions values ('2015-06-20 01:00',1);
insert into actions values ('2015-01-20 01:00',2);
insert into actions values ('2015-03-20 01:00',2);
insert into actions values ('2015-04-20 01:00',2);
insert into actions values ('2015-05-20 01:00',2);
insert into actions values ('2015-05-21 01:00',2);
insert into actions values ('2015-05-21 01:00',2);
insert into actions values ('2015-05-23 01:00',2);
```

I want to check if a user has done at least one action every month for 6 months.

By using this I get how many actions a user has done every month:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month',action_time) AS month_parth, user_id,COUNT(*) AS 
monthly_actions FROM actions
GROUP BY month_parth,user_id
ORDER BY user_id,month_parth ASC;
```

And obtain the following:

**Query #1**

```
SELECT date_trunc('month',action_time) AS month_parth, user_id,COUNT(*) AS monthly_actions FROM actions
GROUP BY month_parth,user_id
ORDER BY user_id,month_parth ASC;
```

| month_parth | user_id | monthly_actions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 6 |
| 2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 1 |
| 2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 1 |
| 2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 1 |
| 2015-06-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 1 |
| 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 1 |
| 2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 1 |
| 2015-04-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 1 |
| 2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 4 |

The user_id 1 has clearly at least one action per month (peaking at 6 on January), but the 2 has some gaps.

I am not sure how to go here, if I would need to do a new query grouping and using HAVING or how to move next.

The desired result could be a simple dummy column with TRUE/FALSE for the users that have at least one action per month during 6 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query where *one_action_per_month_during_next_6_months* is a boolean per user_id and per month which is true if the user executed at least one action in the next comming months :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT date_trunc('month',action_time) AS month_parth
     , user_id, COUNT(*) AS monthly_actions
  FROM actions
 GROUP BY month_parth,user_id
)
SELECT user_id
     , month_parth
     , monthly_actions
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE monthly_actions >=1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY month_parth RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND '6 months' FOLLOWING) = 6 AS one_action_per_month_during_next_6_months
  FROM list AS l
 ORDER BY user_id,month_parth ASC
```

test results in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1ed5a426f097f268fe3bafc7d9076fc6)

Comment: Thanks! Still a bit confused, it looks like the query you proposed only returns true in the month that he had => 6 actions, ideally, I do not care about how many actions per month as long as there is at least one action, then I want to flag that user, output could be just one row per user id, not sure why there is this =6

Comment: You misunderstand the query I propose you. Starting from your query which is in the `WITH list AS (...)` statement, for every resulting row per user_id and per month, I count the **number of rows** (a) which are part of the **window of that row** (b) for which **monthly_actions >= 1** (c) whose **month_parth is in the range betwen the month_parth  of the row and the 6 next months**. You can test my query on some more large data sample in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1ed5a426f097f268fe3bafc7d9076fc6) and tell me if it doesn't correspond to your expectation if so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain it @Eduoard

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select user_id, count(cnt) >= 6 six_months from
(
 select user_id, date_trunc('month', action_time) monthperiod, count(*) cnt
 from actions
 group by user_id, monthperiod
) t
group by user_id;
```

BTW user 1 does not have 6 months with at least one action as he is missing April.